# How to pull dremio data from databricks workspace using pyodbc?

Tags: pyodbc, databricks, dremio

I am able to get data from dremio using pyodbc when I run my python script locally. To make it run locally, I had to install Windows 64 bit odbc driver from the below link using the [guide](https://docs.dremio.com/drivers/dremio-connector.html).

https://www.dremio.com/drivers/

I don't know, how can I install and set it in Databricks workspace. Probably because of this, same code is throwing an error when I try to run it from databricks workspace,

The code to connect to dremio is,

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={};ConnectionType=Direct;HOST={};PORT={};AuthenticationType=Plain;UID={};PWD={}".
                          format(self.driver, self.host, self.port, self.uid, self.pwd),autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Please suggest me a solution.